# NSMutableString Array

Tags: arrays, nsmutablestring

I have an array called AllmyData[10][100000] and would like to concatenate the first 3 elements of each, ie Allmydata[1][i] & Allmydata[2][i] & Allmydata[3][i], into one string

I have tried using NSMutableString, as follows:

```
NSMutableString *xArray[]= [NSMutableString string];

//Create COMPARISSON string
for (i=0; i< 100000; i++) {
    [xArray[i] appendstring:AllmyData[1][i]];
    [xArray[i] appendstring:AllmyData[2][i]];
    [xArray[i] appendstring:AllmyData[3][i]];
    NSLog(xArray[i]);
}
```

However the above does not work..

thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use your mutable string like an array. Try the following:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) 
{
    NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString new];
    [myString appendString:AllmyData[1][i]];
    [myString appendString:AllmyData[2][i]];
    [myString appendString:AllmyData[3][i]];

    [array addObject:myString];

    NSLog(myString);
}
```

However, that'll result in 100,000 log statements. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: NSLogNSLog(myString) is there just for debugging purposes (where i<10). I wanted to avoid introducing an additional variable but by the looks of it, I will have to introduce NSArray *FinalString[100000] and set that equal to (myString). Out of curiosity, I can use an NSString as a c style array why cant i use NSMutableString????

Comment: Why do you want to put your resulting string into an array? I'm not sure why you're going from a 2D array to a string to another array... Regarding not using a mutable string as a C-style array: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be accessing an NSString as a C-style array. According to [this article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/string-philosophies-char-arrays.html) there are no guarantees about how an NSString is represented internally, so you shouldn't rely on that working. There are methods such as `characterAtIndex:` if necessary - you should really treat it like the object it is.

Comment: I have to put into an array because i need to store somewhere the 100000 strings that will be generated by concatenating the other 3 strings.. Unless you can point me towards another direction??

Comment: I've updated my answer to show storing the strings in a mutable array.